# Laravel, вопрос по навигации

Tags: php, laravel, breadcrumbs

[image: Пример навигации]

Подскажте как можно реализовать данную навигацию для ларавел?
суть в том что на каждой странице разделы меняются, как это сделать все динамически
может есть готовый пакет?

Comment: Это не сайт для поиска библиотек https://github.com/davejamesmiller/laravel-breadcrumbs

Comment: Их очень много, я бы порекомендовал этот: https://github.com/davejamesmiller/laravel-breadcrumbs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот пример данной навигации (breadcrumb):

```
   <ol class="breadcrumb">
          <li><a href="{{route('home')}}">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="{{route('homeCategory', ['category_id' => $article['category_id']])}}">{{$article->category['name']}}</a></li>
          <li class="active"><b>{{$article -> title}} </b></li>
  </ol>
```

Я использовал генерацию страниц по текущей категории статьи + название самой статьи.